# associationをoverrideする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

条件が必要なときのみ通常使用している関連名はそのままにwhere句を使用したいと思い、関連の上書きを行う事で可能なのではと思い試してみています。

```
class Hoge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :common
  belongs_to :common_flag, -> { where(flag: 1) }, class_name: 'Common'
  def self.where_flag
    common = common_flag
    super
  end
end
```

railsのドキュメントを参考に、上記のような記述をしましたが、上手くいきませんでした。

```
Hoge.where_flag
```

と呼んだところ、common_flagが"undefined local variable or method"だと言われ、

```
self.common_flag
```

としてみたところ、common_flagが"undefined method"だと言われてしまいました。

正しくはどのように記述すればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

belongs_to は、インスタンスに紐づく関連レコードを取得するものです。

`#<Hoge id: 1, common_id: 1, ...`に対する`#<Common id: 1, ...`を取得するものですからHogeクラス自体からCommonのレコードを取得することはできません。

また`belong_to`は、命名規則通りであれば`common_id`に紐づく1つのレコードを取得するので`where(flag: 1)`は無意味であるため無視されます。

正しい記述方法は、実際どのようなレコードがあって、どういう式でどういう結果を得たいかがないと分かりません。(もしかしたら求めているのはscopeかもしれませんし、そもそもそんな処理を書く必要がないものかもしれません)

### コメントを受けての回答

関連付けは、関連付けの役目だけにすべきだと思います。
(そもそも"上書き"なんてしたら。誰が現状どのような状態にあるか把握できるのでしょう？)
やはりscopeで対応してはどうでしょうか。

```
class School
  has_many :student
  scope :pref, ->(str){ where(prefecture: str) }
end
class Student
  belongs_to :school
  scope :boys, ->{ where(gender: 'male') }
end

School.first.students.boys
```

scopeをmergeすることもできます。

```
School.includes(:students).joins(:students).merge( Student.boys )
Student.includes(:school).joins(:school).merge( School.pref('tokyo') }
```

上記コードは、arelでも掛けます。

```
student_cond = Student.arel_table[:gender].eq('male')
student_cond.to_sql  #=> students.gender = 'male'
School.includes(:students).joins(:students).where(student_cond)
```

ただしこの場合は、includesを使わないと
最初のSchool/Studentのレコードを取得して、関連するstudents/school無指定で再取得試みるので注意が必要です。

ちょっとトリッキーだと。こんなこともできます。

```
scope :has, ->(cond){ where(cond) }
School.incldues(:students).joins(:students).merge( Student.has(gender: 'male') )
```

Comment: 返信が遅くなりすみません。ありがとうございます！諸々納得いたしました。また、例がまずく失礼いたしました。やりたいこととしては、とある関連があったとして、必要に応じてその関連の条件を上書きして変更したい（同じ関連名で、条件を切り替えて使用したい）、いうことになります。

Comment: 追記に気づいておらず、再度の失礼申し訳ありません。おっしゃる通り、上書きは（できたとしても）安易にするものではないですね。scopeで対応するようにいたします。諸々の詳細な例ありがとうございました。参考にさせていただきます。